# Using the word "guess" in a scientific paper

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, science

I wonder if one can use the word *guess* in a scientific paper in the following context:

"... to provide the best guess on answer response time ..."

Would the usage of *prediction* or *estimate* be more appropriate in this context?

Also, the sentence where the *guess* is used is in the introduction which is aimed to be read by people without much knowledge on the subject but with background in science and, probably, a PhD degree.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not "hypothesize"? "to provide the best hypothesis to..."

Comment: Depends, are you *guessing* or something else?

Comment: I think "hypothesize" would be less appropriate since it's on a weeker side from my point of view. As I understand, hypothesis is an explanation of a phenomenon which cannot be explained with the currently available or known scientific theories. On the contrary, _prediction_ and _estimate_ are assumed to be based on some theory, I guess. I would agree that _guess_ is not a good word for science though.

Comment: the problem is that `guess` seems like it isn't based on anything other than the authors' guessing. It sounds like it doesn't have any grounds to stand. On the contrary, `estimate` should have more grounds. When you `hypothesize` you are giving a potential answer to something based on something else. But I guess what we are missing in here is a bit more of context.
For instance, are you trying to come up with some potential explanation for something you already know? or are you trying to predict what will happen?

Comment: Prediction would work. A prediction is based on what is known, and the best prediction would be based on correlation of what is known with past performance.  The knowledge may be incomplete, but you go with what you have, and can measure the confidence statistically.

Comment: Sosi, what you said makes sence to me, especially regarding the meaning of "guess"! Regarding more of context, I'm trying to use historical data in order to predict the future using some established scientific methods. I think I'll write "SWAG" in my paper then! ;-)

Comment: This is really nothing to do with the English language, but about style for scientific papers. The Academia site might be a better venue.

Comment: Yes, scientists never "guess" -- they "hypothesize" or "estimate".

Answer (score 2):

**It's not too welcome,** IMO.

At Google Books, one can test the waters injecting relevant extra words in the search, say "dissertation," which limits the search environment to publications containing "dissertation":

**"provide the best guess" "dissertation"**
About 0 results

**"provide the best estimate" "dissertation"**
About 9 results

Comment: if you include results from Google Scholar it's probably more helpful. 5,550 for your sentence with "estimate", 101 for "guess"